# ARC conversion issue, does it recognize Extensions?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, extension-methods, automatic-ref-counting

I am converting my Objective-C Cocos2d project into ARC and I am finding some issues when trying to convert a third party class that extends some other classes.

Below is the ARC error message I get:

[image]

The static method shown in the issue are defined in the SneakyExtension.h file that extends some other classes (SneakyButton, SneakyButtonSkinnedBase, SneakyJoystick..) in this way (I share only the interface as the code is copyrigthed by Steffen Itterheim):

```
@interface SneakyButtonSkinnedBase (Extension)
+(id) skinnedButton;
@end

@interface SneakyJoystick (Extension)
+(id) joystickWithRect:(CGRect)rect;
@end

@interface SneakyJoystickSkinnedBase (Extension)
+(id) skinnedJoystick;
@end
```

You can find the source code here: [look at the ShootEmUp03 example in chapter 8](http://www.apress.com/downloadable/download/sample/sample_id/640/).

My only guess is that the **Extension** keyword is somehow not supported by ARC but I have a feeling that I am wrong because I haven't found much on google with this as well as neither on Stackoverflow or the "transitioning to ARC" Apple's iTunes U tutorial.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you're importing the .h files for both the SneakyJoystick class and the extensions?

Comment: @PhillipMills yep, you are bang on. I assumed it was ok because it was running with no issues (before attempting the conversion). Now I imported directly "SneakyExtensions.h" that imports all other headers and it is fine (need to check the next ARC errors now, but this is a separate business). I can't quiet understand how it managed to run before.. any hint? Do you want to post your comment as answer and I'll accept it so you get some points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import required files.  :-)

My best guess about why it worked is that the compiler is being more particular about correct declarations now than it was.  Why that should be the case, I have no idea.  In the end, though, it's the runtime that gets the final vote on what works and, as long as there really is a `joystickWithRect` method linked into your app, you're functionally OK even if it **should** have been a compiler error in the earlier builds -- according to some standard.

What you're encountering now doesn't affect the program's behavior; it's just the compiler trying to make sure you're telling it the right thing.

Comment: ARC needs to see the method declaration to reason about the method's return value and memory management implications.

Answer (score 2):

When compiling under ARC, the `joystickWithRect` method needs to be publically declared and imported for you to use it. The compiler needs to have access to the method declaration since it could have been defined with an attribute like `NS_RETURNS_RETAINED` which changes the retain/release calls that the compiler needs to generate.

Previously, it was up to you the developer to handle the retains and releases, so the compiler let you call selectors even if they had not previously been declared.

Comment: thanks for your answer. +1. I haven't accepted it as final as Phillip provided a similarly correct answer in his comment beofore but I am glad for both explanations and I do thank you for the contribution (appreciated).

Comment: No problem, just be aware that this error specifically relates to ARC rather than the result of a stricter compiler like the other answer suggests.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to get my head around on ARC. Have you found any good guide apart the iTunes U material and apple.developer one?

Comment: I would take a look at some of the WWDC 2011 videos at http://developer.apple.com/videos/

Comment: Yep, I had seen a couple but probably I need to study them again :), thanks

Comment: Thanks for the extra information about why the errors are appearing.  Even in a non-ARC world, I would have expected warnings...though, I guess the original question didn't claim the code had been free of warnings.  :-)

Comment: Yeah, no claims about that. Warnings where not the priority at the moment as I was trying to get things compiling at first and look at the "red messages" first :)..